# Select YeAH-TCP like congestion control algorithm to configure kernel

Tags: linux, kernel, tcp

I'm configuring/compiling the 2.6.37 kernel and I want select *YeAH-TCP* like default congestion control algorithm but, although I enable this option (*CONFIG_TCP_CONG_YEAH*), it doesn't show in the congestion control algorithm list to select like default.
What's the sense of this? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Does `tcp_yeah` appear in `/proc/modules` ? If not, you need to `modprobe tcp_yeah`.

Comment: But my doubt is why I can't select it in kernel configuration.

Comment: If you look at net/ipv4/Kconfig:623, YEAH is not an option, probably because it's experimental. It should be easy to hack this, select TCP_CONG_YEAH <*> and then make it default.